# How can I connect to geth by IPC on nodejs?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodejs, ethereumjs

This this the command line i have used to get geth running.

```
geth ipc --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --ipcpath "/root/.ethereum_experiment/geth.ipc"
```

so from node js how to connect to this geth client,
before this i was doing rpc and connected using http providers but i want the connection over IPC not over RPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the [documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started) you can do:

```
$ geth attach ipc:/some/custom/path
$ geth attach http://191.168.1.1:8545
$ geth attach ws://191.168.1.1:8546
```

So the 1st line is what you want, just replace `/some/custom/path` with `/root/.ethereum_experiment/geth.ipc`

edit : just saw you want to do it on nodejs, I didn't test it  but using the provider with `ipc:/some/custom/path` should be ok

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked specifically about Node.js, see my answer to the similar question [Getting contract balance over JSON RPC](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/7024/2530)

TL;DR use the [official web3 JavaScript library](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) which handles connecting to the server over RPC and gives you easy access to query it for data.

See the question I linked for more details.