# Getting contract balance over JSON RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, json-rpc

I'd like to read the contract balance (amount of unspend ETH on the contract) over Geth JSON-RPC API.

E.g. the number displayed here: http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xc5910bcb2442e84845aa98b20ca51e8f5d2bee23

What would be a good starting point?

Comment: Have you tried http://testnet.etherscan.io/apis ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This question is about geth, not etherscan.

Comment: You should specify the programming language you want to use for the client. BokkyPooBah gave an example in shell but may be you were expecting something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example using the Linux utility [`curl`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to retrieve the balance of the contract over [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance):

```
curl -s -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0", "method":"eth_getBalance", "params":["0xc5910bcb2442e84845aa98b20ca51e8f5d2bee23", "latest"], "id":1}' http://localhost:8545
```

You will have to start `geth` with the `--rpc` parameter to run the `curl` program above, e.g.,

```
geth --testnet --rpc console
```

The results you receive will be the number of weis in hexadecimal format:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x58d15e17628000f"}
```

Converting this number using a [Hexadecimal to Decimal Converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) results in a decimal number of `400000000000000015` weis.

To calculate the number of ethers, divide the decimal number by 1e18 and your result is `0.400000000000000015` ethers.

And checking this balance using the `geth` JavaScript console:

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xc5910bcb2442e84845aa98b20ca51e8f5d2bee23"), "ether")
> 0.400000000000000015
```

Here is my Perl code to convert the hex wei number to a double ether number:

```
sub hexToDouble{
  my $param = shift;
  $param =~ s/^0x//;
  my $fullnum = 0.0;
  while ($param =~ /(.)/g) {
    my $num = hex($1);
    $fullnum = $fullnum * 16 + $num;
  }
  $fullnum *= 1e-18;
  return $fullnum;
}
```

Comment: This is querying the ETH balance, not the Contract ( ERC-20 token) balance.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [official web3 JavaScript library](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)'s method [web3.eth.getBalance](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance)

Example Node.js code:

```
Web3 = require('web3');

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var balance = web3.eth.getBalance("0xc5910bcb2442e84845aa98b20ca51e8f5d2bee23");

console.log("Balance = " + web3.fromWei(balance, "ether"));
```

You should change `http://localhost:8545` to point to your own geth server.

Also the documentation linked above has some best practices for not overriding previously defined `web3` objects, but I skipped them for brevity.  Consult the docs yourself to see what all you can do with that lib.

If you cannot use Node.JS then you can read the [Official Ethereum JSON RPC spec](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) which tells you all of the methods available and how to use them.

Comment: is there a function somewhere in go-ethereum codebase that does this conversion as well?