# How to unlock account from web3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc

How to unlock account from web3?

How to enable ipcapi from geth javascript console?

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/how-to-unlock-the-account-with-geth/4159#4159

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5792/how-can-i-connect-to-geth-by-ipc-on-nodejs

Answer (score 2):

Try to use :
`geth --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,personal,web3"`

if it doesn't work drop the ipcapi part.

then unlock the account using the  command :     `web3.personal.unlockAccount("account","password");`

Comment: when i am running --ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,personal,web3" command it is giving me fatal Error- resource not available

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to start geth with rpc and ipc API.

can you please help me resolve this.

Comment: Howe did you start it?

Comment: i am connecting using Putty

Comment: I meant what was the command you've run? geth ...

Comment: read official doc : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console

Comment: geth --ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,personal,web3" this command

Comment: check my answer i ve made some modif

Comment: You may create a unsignes transaction and use Metamask to sign it.